# How do i stop Google Chrome (which is not installed) from launching?

Tags: 11.10, google-chrome, chromium

I do not want to use Google Chrome - I purposely installed Chromium. But whenever I click on a link in an external application ( like a link in a pdf or email) Google chrome launches. It is not in installed applications in software center

Comment: Did you install it from Google at some point and remove it? If you could post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` it could confirm it, Google's package will readd the sources if it finds it missing.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **System Settings** --> **System Info** --> **Default Applications**. Then choose Firefox (or another browser you like) at the point *Web*. 

 I hope I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command to switch your default browser

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

- Now you will have list of browsers in selection numbers, select the browser by entering that selection number and press enter.